# Unable to extract value between two characters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying with so many examples online to get the numbers between a `_` and `.`. It simple outputs empty string for whatever reason.

String:

```
/chat_3.txt
```

I want to be able to extract the number in it, which is `3` in the above string.How do I do that?

I tried as below, but it gives empty output:

```
$s = '/chat_3.txt';
$matches = array();
$t = preg_match('/_(.*?)\./s', $s, $matches);
```

Then, I write the output into a file in Joomla like this:

```
$file = __DIR__ . '/file.txt';
JFile::write($file, $matches[1]);
```

**EDIT**:

In fact, I passed array instead of string.

Comment: @anubhava i get error: Warning</b>:  preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in <b>

Comment: @anubhava, I found the fix, I passed array instead of string ..

Comment: Could you please clarify if your issue is solved or not? If you need to get *numeric* values from the strings in an array, I think you could use [`preg_filter('/.*_(\d+)\..*/s', '$1',$s)`](https://ideone.com/le6LFx)

Answer (score 1):

So, the real issue is that

> I passed array instead of string

If you need to extract the digits from the last occurrence of `.`+`digits`+`.`, you can easily achieve that with a `preg_filter` function:

```
$s = array('/chat_3.txt', '/chat_old.txt', '/chat_15.txt');
$matches = array();
$t = preg_filter('/.*_(\d+)\..*/s', '$1',$s);
print_r($t);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/le6LFx)

The `preg_filter` will return only those values where it found a match. The replaced values will be returned. So, `.*_(\d+)\..*` will match any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last `_` + 1 or more digits (captured into Group 1) + `.` + any zero or more chars up to the end of string, and will replace all this with the digits found in Group 1.